# Extract SquashFS filesystem with shsq magic number

Tags: binary-analysis, file-format, firmware

for a few days I was trying to extract the filesystem of a router firmware. Checking the image that the vendor provides I can see a SquashFS flag on it:

```
DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
52          0x34        uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x1A27096C, created: Tue Nov 27 06:52:32 2012, image size: 3448768 bytes, Data Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x8023A000, data CRC: 0x584BBD98, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Linux Kernel Image"
116         0x74        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 2445108 bytes
983092      0xF0034     Squashfs filesystem, little endian, non-standard signature,  version 3.0, size: 2463170 bytes,  637 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Tue Nov 27 06:51:11 2012
```

Once extracted the file and checking it with hexdump I found the folowing magic number **shsq**:

```
00000000  73 68 73 71 7d 02 00 00  00 00 00 54 03 00 00 08  |shsq}......T....|
00000010  1c 71 b7 a0 12 71 b7 19  1f 73 00 18 03 00 00 00  |.q...q...s......|
00000020  38 72 10 00 c0 02 01 cf  54 b4 50 d4 0c 1f 10 00  |8r......T.P.....|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 01 00 2c  00 00 00 02 00 a2 bf c2  |.......,........|
00000040  95 25 00 00 00 00 00 b6  95 25 00 00 00 00 00 be  |.%.......%......|
```

This is not the first time I found this header, but I couldn't find a solution for extract it.

Things I tried so far:

- All versions of unsquashfs and firmware-mod-tools.
- Modify the header for a known one that the unsquash tool could recognize.
- This patch http://sandeen.net/wordpress/computers/uncompressing-cisco-x2000-firmware-images/

You can find further information of this issue in this link but without solution:

http://forums.modem-help.co.uk/viewtopic.php?t=9668

Anyone has idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: SquashFS has been hacked to support LZMA by many a vendor, so without more information on the vendor/model, it's hard to point to a definitive answer. Have you looked to see if the vendor has any GPL code released for this device (or others)? FWIW, the firmware-mod-kit was able to extract the squashfs image from the link in Igor Skochinsky's answer, which has the same magic bytes.

Comment: Actually `firmware-mod-kit` does support LZMA. I ran into a similar problem with a Zyxel router which also used a modified version of `squashfs` and managed to get around it, but the respective libs need to be available at compile time, IIRC.

Comment: @Nucklear: are you trying to extract this on a 32 or 64 bit system? I've had issues with hacked up unsquashfs tools not working properly on 64 bit systems.

Comment: @devttys0 Hi, this is the vendor website for this model: http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/single-band-routers/airstation-n150-wireless-router I don't see any GPL code there, and I'm using a 64bits kali distro. I'm going to test it on a 32bits system and post here the result. Regards

Comment: @devttys0 Yes, you were right the problem was doing it in a 64bits system, I prepared a 32bits VM and uncompresed it with squashfs-3.2-r2-lzma included on the last version of firmware-mod-kit

Comment: On linux: unsquashfs filename

Answer (score 6):

`0x73687371` is apparently a magic value used to indicate LZMA compression [by some vendors](http://sourceforge.net/p/squashfs/patches/20/).

I can't test it since I don't have the image but here's a blog post with some description and source code links which is supposed to handle it:

http://www.poppopret.org/?p=204

**EDIT**: after some struggle with the download site I was able to get the decrypted shsq binary. I could open it easily with **7-Zip 9.21 beta**:

[image]

Presumably any later versions will work too.

You can find the source code for handling SquashFS in [7z922.tar.bz2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/7z922.tar.bz2/download), file `CPP/7zip/Archive/SquashfsHandler.cpp` so you can try to figure out why it works and what's wrong with other approaches.

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your response but as you can see I posted a comment in that blog (Last comment) but that solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the patch from:
http://sourceforge.net/p/squashfs/patches/20/

It seems to work ok on an X86_64 Debian installation.